# Is Bias FX viable for live performances?

Tags: amplifiers, live, amplification

I’m considering using bias fx through an iPad for live performance and was wondering about running it through a PA system. I don’t have any high quality amps, and I’ve been really loving the tones of bias through my headphones - so was wondering how close to these I can get running direct into a PA system from my iPad? In theory, if I like the tones of bias fx and the amp sims it provides, does that mean I could go without an amp ever again?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. I have used Bias FX and garage band live with my iPad. I used it for small setups when I didn’t feel my full pedal board and amp was worth hauling for such a small gig. It works.
The drawback is battery life of course.

Comment: How do you find it compares sonically to your pedal board, or even to how it sounds through headphones vs PA?

Comment: @Numpy it’s not the exact same sound of my pedals, of course, but it sounds the same through the PA as a microphone on an amp would. The sound will be the same difference as listening to an mp3 with headphone vs a PA.